# Colourise ruby syntax from 'cat' output

Tags: ruby, shell, colors, cat

I want to be able to get colours for Ruby (or C# or F#) in the shells.

wirble does it nicely with IRB, but I want to be able to do:

`> cat rakefile.rb | colorize`

Does somebody know how I could do this? I know that github's language parsers are OSS - could they be used to read lines one by one and colourise them?

Answer (score 2):

pygments does that for you: http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/

Comment: and you can just make an alias in you `.bashrc` like described in http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/tools/cat_syntax_highlighting/

Comment: That just does this: ```xyz@ISOMORPHISM /d/code/oss/lib (dev)
$ cat rubyfile.rb | pygmentize
Usage: c:\Python27\Scripts\pygmentize-script.py [-l <lexer> ...``` , i.e. it's not reading anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`source-highlight`](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/source-highlight.html) as well.